# iCloud Documents syncing, but can't be opened on other devices

Tags: ios, synchronization, icloud, uidocument

I have a document based iCloud app that is giving me grief. Things used to work on iOS 7, but now they don't. I think it dates back to iOS 8.0 upgrade. Here's the problem:

In my app I create a `UIDocument` in iCloudURL/subDir and everything works fine on that device (call it DeviceA). I can close the app, start it again and read the file. Great! So I break out my second test device (DeviceB) and my directory query finds the all files I created on DeviceA. However, when I try to open them I get 'NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260' which basically means "no such file or directory". Similarly, if I create files on DeviceB I can't open them DeviceA.

Another point of interest is that if I check "Setting->iCloud->Storage-Manage Storage -> AppName", the files are listed on **BOTH** devices regardless of where they were created.

So obviously I have some kind of iCloud sync problem, but I don't understand what's going on at all. Since iCloud seems to know the files exist, why aren't they syncing properly? Any ideas would be appreciated!

I can add code if that would help, but right now I'm not even sure what to show since most of it works as long as I stay on one device.

Cheers

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I believe the problem was that I was calling OpenWithCompletionHandler multiple times on the same file. I'll post it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling

```
[UIDocument openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success)]
```

multiple times on the same document before any one of them completed.